# Show that this Dirichlet problem can only have a maximum of one solution

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \times \overline{U}$ be a function such that
$f\mid_\mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable and
$f\mid_\overline{U}$ is continuous.
Further let $\frac{\partial }{\partial u} f(u,y) \geq0$ for every $(u,y) \in \mathbb{R} \times U$

Show that the problem
$\Delta u=f(u,y)$ in $U$,
and $u=u_D$ on the boundary of $U$
has at most one Solution.

I am stuck on this problem for a few days now, and can't figure out how to solve it.
In most of my attempts I tried to use the maximum principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $u,v \in C^2(U) \cap C^0(\overline U)$ solve $$\Delta u=f(u,x), \text{ in } U \qquad u=g \text{ on } \partial U .$$ Let $w:=u-v$. If $w\not\equiv 0$ then there exists some point $x\in U$ such that $w(x)\neq 0$. Without loss of generality, we may assume there exists $x \in U$ such that $w(x)>0$. Let $V:= \{x \in U \text{ s.t. } w(x)>0\}$ which is non-empty and open since $u$ and $v$ are continuous. Then for each $x\in V$, \begin{align*}
\Delta w &= f(u,x)-f(v,x) \\
&= \int_{v(x)}^{u(x)} \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(z,x) \, dz \\
&\geqslant 0.
\end{align*} Hence, $w$ is subharmonic in $V$. Since $u$ and $v$ agree on $\partial U$, we have that $w=0$ on $\partial V$. By the maximum principle, $$\max_{\overline V} w = \max_{\partial V} w =0. $$ This is a contradiction with the definition of $V$.